How to create a time delay (24h) using the LTC2956
I’m currently working on a project, for which I’m developing a system that should run for 24 hours. After 24 hours it should turn off to lessen the power consumption. I’m trying to develop this system without the use of a MCU, since I want it to be a simple system without the need for programming.
For the circuit I have found a LTC2956, which is a wake-up timer. The circuit is supplied by 2 AA-batteries (3.3V).
My issue is that when I try to simulate the circuit, it only stays on for 18 seconds and then shuts down the LDO. I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong, but like I said I want the system to stay active for 24 hours and then shut down the LDO.
I have set up a simulation circuit using LTspice and my design looks like this:

The R2 value is taken from table 1 in the datasheet and R1 is calculated using the formula in the datasheet:
R_PERIOD = 400 * (t_PERIOD/NRANGE) [Kohm/s]. 
NRANGE can be found using table 1 and t_PERIOD is set to 86400 s (24 hours). The simulation plot can be seen in the picture below.

The green graph is the output from the LDO and the blue graph is the EN output from the LTC2956.

system without the use of a MCU is not necessarily synonymous with a simple system

Why 24 hours? 24 hours is a full day which is not ideal for auto-shutoff. Should be like 2 or 3 hours

I think you need a 100k resistor between pins LONG and RANGE, and also you don't have a resistor from LONG to ground. Double check the data sheet examples.

Thank you for your reply @Justme. I have tried to add a 100K resistor between LONG and RANGE pins, but that didn't have any impact for the simulation. I have also tried adding a resistor between LONG and ground according to table 2, but this controls how long the system should stay active if using the LONG pin. The maximum time is 16.4 seconds by leaving the LONG pin open. But it should be possible to let the system stay active for 24 hours, I just don't know how. I have a little trouble finding it in the datasheet.

It doesn't look like you are connecting the pins correctly.  You need to leave the \$\overline{\text{PB}}\$ (pushbutton) input floating and tie the \$\text{OnMax}\$ pin to ground, as shown below.  Read each pins' description in the datasheet to see what state to leave them in when you don't want to use each feature.

Keep in mind that for any built-in Linear Tech or Analog Devices part, you can always right-click the symbol and click "Open this macromodel's test fixture" to look at an example schematic which utilizes the part.


this is nearly what I want to accomplish. By the way thank you for right-click suggestion. Now my simulation is active all of the time, but I want it to shut down after 24 hours. The datasheet states that the ONMAX pin controls the maximum allowed awake time. Can you tell me if I have to use this pin to set awake time for 24 hours and if then it automatically shuts down?

@Aki  So you want the system active for 24hr?  How long do you want the system idle in between the active parts? $t_{PERIOD}$ is the idle time, not the active time.  Therefore, the resistors control how long the system is off before it wakes up.

Yes I want it active for 24 hours. The system must be active for 24 hours as it needs to polarise a sensor. After the 24 hours, the system must be switched off and must remain switched off until the user switches the system on again.

@Aki So a person has to wake the system up? I’m not sure you picked the correct part for this…
